# MongoDB connection URI for SSL

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, mongo-java-driver, mongo-java, mongo-jdbc-driver

I'm working on **JDK8** and using **mongo-java-driver(v3.5.0)** to connect **MongoDB(v3.6.3)**.

I've enabled SSL by following [this article](https://rajanmaharjan.medium.com/secure-your-mongodb-connections-ssl-tls-92e2addb3c89). I don't have `/etc/mongod.conf` file, instead I've `/etc/mongodb.conf` file; so I've updated the SSL settings in that file:

```
# SSL options
# Enable SSL on normal ports
sslOnNormalPorts = true
# SSL Key file and password
sslPEMKeyFile = /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
sslPEMKeyPassword = PASSWORD
```

I'm able to access mongo via mongo shell using:

```
mongo --ssl --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/rootCA.pem --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem --host localhost
```

I want to connect MongoDB using Java driver. I initially tried the following JDBC connection string:

```
mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/?ssl=true&sslAllowInvalidCertificates=true&sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
```

but as per [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.6/reference/connection-string/), there are no such options available. Also, I get error:

```
The connection string contains an invalid host 'localhost:27017/?ssl=true&sslAllowInvalidCertificates=true&sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl'. The port '27017/?ssl=true&sslAllowInvalidCertificates=true&sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl' is not a valid, it must be an integer between 0 and 65535
```

And when I try with the following connection string:

```
url=mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/?ssl=true
```

I get following error:

```
 com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:445) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar:?]
.
...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
.
...
```

Here's the code that I've used:

```
String url = "mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@localhost/?authSource=admin&ssl=true"
MongoClientURI connectionURI = new MongoClientURI(url)
mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionURI)
```

Could someone help me with what JDBC connection string I need to configure to connect successfully. Thank you.

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/#connection-options

Comment: @AlexBlex I had tried this as well: `mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@localhost/?authSource=admin&ssl=true`

And I keep getting the same exception related to


`com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:445) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar:?]
.
...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
.
...`

Comment: @AlexBlex
Is there any additional configurations I need to do to make this run?

Comment: To run what exactly? show at least some code how you connect.

Comment: @AlexBlex, I've updated my question and added the code used.

Comment: The error message says `javax.net.ssl.` complains it's "unable to find valid certification path", Did you add the pem to the trust store? if so, show the code

Comment: Sorry @AlexBlex, I was out for couple of weeks. So I setup a MongoDB v4.4. Tried with new Java driver v3.12.11. Updated my connection URI to `mongodb://localhost:27017/?ssl=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem&tlsCAFile=/etc/ssl/rootCA.pem`

Also imported pem files using keytool but I still get the same error.

Comment: Any update on this? I am also facing the same issue.